# Unable to play video with AVPlayerViewController in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer, avkit

I am using simple piece of code to play video in iOS, and it was working perfectly fine till iOS 14, but suddenly this piece of code is not able to play .mov and .mp4 files in iOS 15

```
let videoController = AVPlayerViewController()
videoController.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
from.present(videoController, animated: true) {
  videoController.player?.play()
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: played a sample mp4 URL on iPhone (15.2)  and it worked fine.

Comment: Check the codec of the video file. I know there are issues with playing any Apple ProRes 422 videos.

Comment: The video is working fine on simulator with iOS 15.2, but on real device I am facing issue

Comment: Issue was because I was using speech recognizer and AudioSession set for speech recognition wouldn't let video to be played, so instead I have to change the category of audio session to .playAndRecord